Proving Exact Answers to Logistics Map for 3-Cycles
Seems that I may have found a pair of exact solutions to the logistics map with cycles of period three. However, I’ve run into a bit of a snag in proving it because of some “ambiguities” in the resulting trigonometric identities. I have a pair of trigonometric expressions that give the same numeric value, but the expressions themselves seem somewhat different, and I don’t see how to prove equivalence.
In the following there are the three recurrence relations and the resulting equations are factored using an r value of 23/6 to yield 2 separate cubic equations that each have 3 real roots:
In[30]:= z1a = r z0a (1 - z0a) // Simplify
Out[30]= -r (-1 + z0a) z0a

In[31]:= z2a = r z1a (1 - z1a) // Expand
Out[31]= r^2 z0a - r^2 z0a^2 - r^3 z0a^2 + 2 r^3 z0a^3 - r^3 z0a^4

In[32]:= z3a = r z2a (1 - z2a) // Expand (* z3a should equal z0a *)
Out[32]= 
r^3 z0a - r^3 z0a^2 - r^4 z0a^2 - r^5 z0a^2 + 2 r^4 z0a^3 + 
 2 r^5 z0a^3 + 2 r^6 z0a^3 - r^4 z0a^4 - r^5 z0a^4 - 6 r^6 z0a^4 - 
 r^7 z0a^4 + 6 r^6 z0a^5 + 4 r^7 z0a^5 - 2 r^6 z0a^6 - 6 r^7 z0a^6 + 
 4 r^7 z0a^7 - r^7 z0a^8

In[33]:= 
fn$z1[r_, z0a_] := 
 r^3 z0a - z0a - r^3 z0a^2 - r^4 z0a^2 - r^5 z0a^2 + 2 r^4 z0a^3 + 
  2 r^5 z0a^3 + 2 r^6 z0a^3 - r^4 z0a^4 - r^5 z0a^4 - 6 r^6 z0a^4 - 
  r^7 z0a^4 + 6 r^6 z0a^5 + 4 r^7 z0a^5 - 2 r^6 z0a^6 - 6 r^7 z0a^6 + 
  4 r^7 z0a^7 - r^7 z0a^8 (* note the subtraction of z0a from z3a*)

In[109]:= eqn$3a = 
 r^3 z0a - z0a - r^3 z0a^2 - r^4 z0a^2 - r^5 z0a^2 + 2 r^4 z0a^3 + 
   2 r^5 z0a^3 + 2 r^6 z0a^3 - r^4 z0a^4 - r^5 z0a^4 - 6 r^6 z0a^4 - 
   r^7 z0a^4 + 6 r^6 z0a^5 + 4 r^7 z0a^5 - 2 r^6 z0a^6 - 
   6 r^7 z0a^6 + 4 r^7 z0a^7 - r^7 z0a^8 /. 
  r -> 23/6 (* note the subtraction of z0a from z3a*)

Out[109]= (11951 z0a)/216 - (8553401 z0a^2)/7776 + (
 196728223 z0a^3)/23328 - (9026271455 z0a^4)/279936 + (
 148035889 z0a^5)/2187 - (3700897225 z0a^6)/46656 + (
 3404825447 z0a^7)/69984 - (3404825447 z0a^8)/279936

In[110]:= eqn$3b = Together[eqn$3a]
Out[110]= (1/279936)(15488496 z0a - 307922436 z0a^2 + 
  2360738676 z0a^3 - 9026271455 z0a^4 + 18948593792 z0a^5 - 
  22205383350 z0a^6 + 13619301788 z0a^7 - 3404825447 z0a^8)

Create functions for the two cubics and plot them:
fn$z2[z0a_] := -1026 + 9177 z0a - 20102 z0a^2 + 
  12167 z0a^3 (* one of the two cubics *)

fn$z3[z0a_] := -888 + 8510 z0a - 19573 z0a^2 + 
  12167 z0a^3 (* second of two cubics*)

Plot[{fn$z2[z], fn$z3[z]}, {z, 0, 1}]


Following that, the equation is solved and the complex-valued solutions are converted into cosine functions with ComplexExpand:
In[115]:= sols4a = 
 Solve[r^3 z0a - r^3 z0a^2 - r^4 z0a^2 - r^5 z0a^2 + 2 r^4 z0a^3 + 
    2 r^5 z0a^3 + 2 r^6 z0a^3 - r^4 z0a^4 - r^5 z0a^4 - 6 r^6 z0a^4 - 
    r^7 z0a^4 + 6 r^6 z0a^5 + 4 r^7 z0a^5 - 2 r^6 z0a^6 - 
    6 r^7 z0a^6 + 4 r^7 z0a^7 - r^7 z0a^8 == z0a, z0a, 
  Assumptions -> r == 23/6, Cubics -> True]

Out[115]= {{z0a -> 0}, {z0a -> 17/23}, {z0a -> 
   1/69 (38 + 247^(2/3)/(2 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(
      1/3) + (247 (2 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3))}, {z0a -> 
   38/69 - (247^(2/3) (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(
    138 (2 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(1/3)) - 
    1/138 (1 - I Sqrt[3]) (247 (2 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3)}, {z0a -> 
   38/69 - (247^(2/3) (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(
    138 (2 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(1/3)) - 
    1/138 (1 + I Sqrt[3]) (247 (2 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3)}, {z0a -> 
   1/69 (37 + 259^(2/3)/(4 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(
      1/3) + (259 (4 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3))}, {z0a -> 
   37/69 - (259^(2/3) (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(
    138 (4 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(1/3)) - 
    1/138 (1 - I Sqrt[3]) (259 (4 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3)}, {z0a -> 
   37/69 - (259^(2/3) (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(
    138 (4 + 9 I Sqrt[3])^(1/3)) - 
    1/138 (1 + I Sqrt[3]) (259 (4 + 9 I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3)}}

In[124]:= rt1$sol4a = sols4a[[3, 1, 2]] // ComplexExpand
Out[124]= 38/69 + 2/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]

In[125]:= rt2$sol4a = sols4a[[4, 1, 2]] // ComplexExpand
Out[125]= 38/69 - 1/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] - 
 1/23 Sqrt[247/3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]

In[126]:= rt3$sol4a = sols4a[[5, 1, 2]] // ComplexExpand
Out[126]= 38/69 - 1/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] + 
 1/23 Sqrt[247/3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]

Of particular note is that applying the recurrence function to each of the three numeric values of the roots produces the next root in the cycle:
In[129]:= {{N[rt1$sol4a], 
  rcr$fn$1a[23/6, N[rt1$sol4a]]}, {N[rt2$sol4a], 
  rcr$fn$1a[23/6, N[rt2$sol4a]]}, {N[rt3$sol4a], 
  rcr$fn$1a[23/6, 
   N[rt3$sol4a]]}} (* numeric roots and applying recurrence function \
to each*)
Out[129]= {{0.954565, 0.166255}, {0.166255, 0.531354}, {0.531354, 
  0.954565}}

So the numeric values of the three roots of one of the two cubics are cyclically related and exact -- as are the roots of the other cubic. So one might assume the equations and derivations are correct as well. So the question is whether applying the recurrence relation to the symbolic expression for the third root gives an expression identical to the first root:
In[131]:= rt4a$sol4a = 
 rcr$fn$1a[23/6, 
  rt3$sol4a] (* applying recurrence function to third root (0.531354)*)
Out[131]= 23/6 (31/69 + 
   1/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] - 
   1/23 Sqrt[247/3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]) (38/69 - 
   1/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] + 
   1/23 Sqrt[247/3] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]])

rt4b$sol4 = 
 rt4a$sol4a // Simplify (* 
  comparing symbolic expressions which should be identical*)
Out[135]= -(1/1242)(-31 - Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] + 
    Sqrt[741] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]) (38 - 
    Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] + 
    Sqrt[741] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]])

In[136]:= rt1$sol4a (* for reference*)
Out[136]= 38/69 + 2/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]

In[138]:= {N[rt1$sol4a], N[rt4b$sol4]} 
Out[138]= {0.954565, 0.954565}

(* comparing numeric values; identical even though symbolic expression for rt4b is much more complicated than the starting point of the progression, i.e., rt1$sol4a. So, how to prove the two expressions are identical*)
I see that Eric Weisstein https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html over on MathWorld has a decent, and quite lengthy article on the logistics map. And he has said that "The only exact solutions known are for r=-2, r=2 and r=4", so either I've made a serious mistake somewhere in the above, or I got incredibly lucky in finding at least one exception to that rule. Whether there might be others -- assuming r=23/6 is one such exception -- seems an interesting question, though one well outside my salary range. Although I did try several other fractions in the same ballpark -- no luck. Still, it would be nice to know if there are others -- and whether that exception might shed some light on the phenomenon.

Try FullSimplify, it works here. a = 38/69 + 2/69 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] ; b = -(1/1242) (-31 - Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] +       Sqrt[741] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]) (38 -       Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] +       Sqrt[741] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]]) ; a - b // FullSimplify

LoL
In[139]:= (rt1$sol4a - rt4b$sol4) // FullSimplify
Out[139]= 0
Thanks muchly.

@I.M. Thanks again, though I kinda think FullSimplify uses numeric values. And when I use Simplify or TrigReduce I still get trig expressions that aren't clear as to how they would be identical to zero:
In[143]:= (rt1$sol4a - rt4b$sol4) // TrigReduce
Out[143]= (1/1242)(29 Sqrt[247] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] -
247 Cos[2/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] +
7 Sqrt[741] Sin[1/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]] -
247 Sqrt[3] Sin[2/3 ArcTan[(9 Sqrt[3])/2]])
